# POJOMappingFeature for HTTP errors?

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, jax-rs

I have `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` set to true and it works fine for HTTP 200 responses.

However, when my application returns an error, it shows text/html response with error headline instead.

Even if I create my custom exception (in ContainerRequestFilter) like this:

```
throw new WebApplicationException(
    Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
      .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .build()
);
```

It still shows generic text/html 403 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the ExceptionMapper from Jersey:

First, your Custom Exception:

```
public class UnauthorizedException extends RuntimeException {
   public UnauthorizedException() {}
}
```

Then, your Entity, you want to send back:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ErrorMessage{
  @XmlElement
  private String message;

  public ErrorMessage(String message){
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

And finally, the Magic kicks in :)

```
@Provider
public class UnauthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnauthorizedException>{

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(UnauthorizedException exception) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                   .entity(new ErrorMessage("Not Authorized"))
                   .build();
   }
 }
```

Now, a JSON-Entity should be returned when you

```
throw new UnauthorizedException();
```

Regards

Comment: Great, thank you! The entity() call is the key, without it the media() type is not respected.